# How to Sort String in array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am using this function to sort names in a string array alphabatically. But it is not working. If anyone has best solution for it, kindly Answer this question.

```
void List::sort_Name()
{
    string temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cap; j++)
        {
            if (Prolist[i].getName() < Prolist[i + 1].getName())
            {

                temp = Prolist[i].getName();
                Prolist[i].getName() = Prolist[i + 1].getName();
                Prolist[i + 1].getName() = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]. What is `prolist`? What is `getName`?

Comment: Have you considered storing the strings in a `std::vector` and use `std::sort` provided by the `<algorithm>` header?

Comment: Your inner loop is useless, it just does the same thing `cap` times. If `i` and `i+1` are out of order then swap them, but you only need to do that once, there's no point doing it `cap` times.

Comment: How do you know when the list is finally sorted? Try to sort an array of integers, first. Once you understand how it works, proceed with strings.

Comment: The best solution for sorting is a very complicated question. Would you be prepared to accept any solution that works?

Comment: Do not use loops for sorting (and for searching) in C++! It's inefficient and produces more code. Use the appropriate built-in functions! (google: sort, find, find_if).

Comment: @Zoltán its not necessarily inefficient, sort eventually also uses loops, its just very unlikely that something selfmade will be more efficient

Answer (score 3):

Disregarding the incomplete code snippet provided, this is how you sort strings in c++:

```
std::list<std::string> strings{ "foo", "bar", "baz", "test" };
strings.sort();
for (std::string s : strings) {
    std::cout << "string: " << s << std::endl;
}
```

It produces the output:

```
string: bar
string: baz
string: foo
string: test
```

Also works with `std::vector` instead of `std::list`, that's more performant in lots of use cases, instead of `strings.sort();` you would call `std::sort(strings.begin(), strings.end());`.

Comment: why do you assume its a `std::list` ? OP says " sort names in a string array". Anyhow, you already mention vector and I already did upvote ;)

Comment: True that, he actually has plain C arrays in his code snippet. But that code wan't complete and it's not obvious how to get it to run, so I opted to just post a simple solution for the problem he's trying to solve. Sorry if this caused any confusion!

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the strings as below too:

```
std::array<std::string,4> strings{ "foo", "bar", "baz", "test" };
std::sort(strings.begin(),strings.end());
for (std::string s : strings) {
    std::cout << "string: " << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Prolist` is a `std::vector`, a `std::array` or a
c-style array, then the following would work:
(I'm assuming the type of a `ProList` item is `Item`,
replace as necessary)

```
#include <algorithm>

void List::sort_Name()
{
    auto beg = std::begin(Prolist);
    auto end = std::end(Prolist);
    auto less = [](const Item& lhs, const Item& rhs) -> bool
    {
        return lhs.getName() < rhs.getName();
    };
    std::sort(beg, end, less);
}
```

Furthermore, `getName()` is assumed to be a const method, as it should be,
and it is assumed to return something that can be compared with `<`

This works by creating a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), that do the item comparison, and
using the standard library algorithm `std::sort`

If `Prolist` is a `std::list` you instead use:

```
    Prolist.sort(less);
```

and don't need the iterators.

If `Prolist` is dynamically allocated memory, you acquire the
iterators using:

```
    auto beg = Prolist;
    auto end = Prolist + cap; // <- 'cap' or what holds the number of items
```

But may I suggest that you replace your manual memory management with `std::vetor` in that case, due to [Single Responsibility Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: @user463035818 OP wanted to sort by the return value of `getName()`. Calling `sort()` with its default comparison would compare `Item` itself, which may produce a different order (or not provide a comparison operator at all).

Comment: ups sorry, you are right

Comment: example here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86e2233b8c84ff93